# How to avoid object class conflicts between data class and service proxies

Tags: entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services

I've seen similar questions but nothing that directly addresses the challenge I'm facing...

First, I generally create my WCF client proxies manually because I just find them easier to deal with in the long run.  However, this isn't really an option when dealing with WCF Data Services and EF because so much is done "behind the scenes"...

In my scenario I have a WCF service that calls a WCF Data Service.  The calling service receives data from a client which passes entity objects generated by EF.  These entity objects are in an assembly referenced by the data service also.

When I generate a client proxy in VS2010, the objects are put in a different namespace so I can do a direct cast from the data object received from the client to the proxy class.  To resolve this I've modified the proxy's reference.cs file and changed the namespace... that seems to work but generates a ton of conflict warnings...

Does anyone have a cleaner way to do this?  I don't mind generating the proxy manually with some guidance because it looks pretty complex.

Thanks,
KBW

Additional Information... below is the warning message I receive from the wrapper service after I changed the namespace in the WCF Data service client proxy.

The type 'AW.Data.Demo.Contact' in C:\Azure\Tutorials\MyFirstAzureProject\awEntityData\awEntityData\Service References\AWEntityModel\Reference.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'Maevva.iSvr.Data.Demo.Contact' in 'c:\Assemblies\AWDataModelLib.dll'. Using the type defined in 'C:\ Azure\Tutorials\MyFirstAzureProject\awEntityData\awEntityData\Service References\AWEntityModel\Reference.cs'. C:\Azure\Tutorials\MyFirstAzureProject\awEntityData\awEntityData\Custom Data\awEntityData.cs

Comment: Thanks Gert.  The objects I'm exposing are the AdventureWorks database entities.  As a POC I've simply used EF to generate a model from the AW database and as part of a c# class library.  I reference that library in the WCF Data service and in the wrapper service described above...

Comment: Why do you need to reference the EF model in the wrapper service? It seems that service will only access the actual EF data through the WCF Data Service, so there should be no need for it to know about the underlying EF.

Comment: For the final development, I plan to create an entity model using the Model First workflow.  I then want to package this model for use in building several services... for example, I may want to provide the data to a client application which will need to reference the objects in the entity model.  I don't want the client application to have to reference the data service... it should be able to reference a data class that contains the entity model without all the other "stuff" that comes with a service reference.  I hope this makes sense.